# Post preview description eliminates BR tags in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

using WP, when I type in paragraph and then press "Shift Enter" it goes to new line (if we see html code, it places 
). But when I see in the homepage recent posts preview short description, it shows plain text without br effect. How to tackle this issue?

Post Editor View Screenshot:

[View Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB4hv.png)

Preview on Homepage:

[View Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpeOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br>` to your text to break text line. [Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Comment: i added <br> and many of them to test, but on homepage post description, it ommits all <br>'s.

Comment: Are you using text editor? You could also follow [this instructions](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/wordpress-line-break-not-working/) for the problem.